# passing user input to another component in vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, components

I'm fairly new to vue.js but I couldn't seem to find a concrete answer for what I'm looking for but I also am new enough that I might have been looking right at the answer and not known it. So.

What I'm trying to do is create a 1 page application that tracks turns basically.
It will:

1. takes user input on how many users are participating
2. ask for the names of all the users
3. use the names which I currently have saved in an array, to build user cards, just showing the name of each user.
4. You will click your name when your turn is over and the next persons card/button will 'raise' and then they click it, etc.

I'm currently having a hard time with that 3rd part. I need to figure out how I can pass this array of users to my other component's data object so I can use vue.js to loop and just spit the cards out.

**initial-start.vue - template**

```
<template lang="html">
 <div>
  <div>
   <h1>How many users?</h1>
   <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="0">
   <button v-on:click="getUsers">Submit</button>
   <app-area v-if="users > 0 && users < 5"></app-area>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

**initial-start.vue - script**

```
<script>
export default {
methods:{
getUsers(){
  var counter = 0;
  var users = [];
  var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
  if (x <= 0){
    alert('Please choose a number greater than 0.');
  }else if(x > 4){
    alert('Maximum 4 users!');
  }else{
    alert('thank you for that.')
  }
    while(counter < x){
      name = prompt('Please enter your names.');
      users.push(name);
      counter++;
    }
    return users;
  }
}
}
</script>
```

**app-area.vue - template**

```
<template lang="html">
 <div>
  <h1>Turn: {{ turn }}</h1>
  <userCards></userCards>
 </div>
</template>
```

**app-area.vue - script**

```
<script>
 export default {
  data() {
   return{
    turn: 0,
    users: []
   }
  },
props: ['users']
}
</script>
```

The question is, "How do I get the array from the getUsers() function, into the app area where I would be able to loop like

```
<userCards v-for="user in users"></userCards>
```

and have a card/button for each person entered ?"

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props

Answer (score 0):

You should save the value of `getUser` in your data, and then you can pass that to your `app-area` component.

```
data: {
  users: 0
}
methods:{
getUsers(){
  @users = 2;
}
```

And then in your html:

```
<app-area v-if="users > 0 && users < 5" v-bind:users="users"></app-area>
```

Now your `app-area` template has access to `users`. So you can pass each user to `userCard` component

```
<userCards v-for="user in users" v-bind:user="user"></userCards>
```

Comment: Thank you this mostly seems to have worked for me. I'm getting some other warnings now about the componenet lists should have explicit keys. It's not keeping the app from working entirely but it's not functioning the way I'd want it to yet

    (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) <userCards v-for="user in users">: component lists rendered with v-for should have explicit keys.

Comment: You can set a key like this: 

`<userCards v-for="user in users" v-bind:user="user" v-bind:key="user.id">`

Comment: I'm still having trouble here, it seems all of your code and logic is correct but the app isn't doing anything still. I can't seem to determine if the method is sending the data out of the component or not, becuase it doesn't seem like it. I can't even call the value for users inside the same component. I've made a  seperate button that is simply suppose to alert users but it doesn't - trying to alert it manually in the console it says that users is undefined.

I placed my whole app project in a repo on github so you can see the whole thing https://github.com/Yintii/trackerapp

Comment: The first trouble I see is that you're accessing your data wrong. You have `data.users = users`. Try accessing it like `this.users = users`. Make the same change in your `check` function.